# How to access .env variable inside _app.js file

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, next.js

env file

```
ID=123
```

I am able access this variable inside my pages/index.js file by
`${process.env.ID}`
but when I am trying same in my _app.js file its giving undefined, can anyone please suggest me how I can access this inside my _app.js file.

Answer (score 3):

in next.config.js, define

`env: { ID: process.env.ID },`

Comment: Then how can I call it inside _app.js
I tried your solution and called ${process.env.ID} inside _app.js, still undefined

Comment: @PujaGarg you can directly use it in the _app.js like "ID".

Answer (score 3):

You can use `process.env` but for security reasons the vars need to start with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` (explained [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser)).

In the `.env`,

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_ID=123
```

In the `_app.js` (or any front-end code),

```
process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ID
```

Comment: this answer is not correct, because the front-end cannot read envirement constants . this should be read in server and properly in getStaticsProps